# Star Trek - Weapon of Peace

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

This piece of Star Trek has been eating me for a while.

Many years ago, I saw an episode of Star Trek - it was either the original or TNG.  The Enterprise crew comes across a strange device which turns out to be a weapon of "peace".  It was advanced and powerful enough to destroy any known weapon.  But it did not attack anyone who was unarmed and I recall the captain ordering the crew not to even "think" violent thoughts.  The weapon then seemed pacified and caused no further harm.

Which series/episode was this?  What was the name of the weapon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was a 2 part episode of TNG, *The Gambit*, the weapon was called the Stone of Gol.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response........